# How to prevent methods from being called if something went wrong within __init__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I'm building this class called LanguagePack. It loads a .csv files from harddrive and parse it. I broke the initialisation process into 3 separate functions (**is this appropriate?**) and I want to disabled all methods if this initialisation failed.

```
class LanguagePack:
    def __init__ (self):
        try:
            self._read ()
            self._validator ()
            self._slice ()

        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            print ('File is not in UTF-8 (BOM) encoding.')
        except KeyError:
            print ('Column name incomplete.')
        except:
            print ('Unknown error.')

        else:
            pass

    def _read (self):
        pass

    def _validator (self):
        pass

    def _slice (self):
        pass

    def foo (self):
        pass
```

Currently even if something went wrong during initialisation, the methods (like foo) is still callable. These method are dependent on the variables created during initialisation. Unpredicatable errors would occur.

Comment: If the exception can't be handled and recovered from, don't catch it...

Comment: If an object cannot be properly instantiated, its entire instantiation must be aborted. You do that by *raising an exception*. In your case: simply don't *catch* the exceptions that are already being raised.

Comment: Well thank you guys... But what if I want to tell the user what when wrong and still ends this programme, can I write another raise within except?

Comment: You can simply put `raise` after your log message, which will re-reraise the exception you just caught.

Comment: I would suggest doing said logging in `_read`, `_validator`, or `_slice`, rather than catching the exception in `__init__` to do the logging.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest thing to do is re-raise each exception you haven't handled.

```
class LanguagePack:
    def __init__ (self):
        try:
            self._read ()
            self._validator ()
            self._slice ()

        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            print ('File is not in UTF-8 (BOM) encoding.')
            raise
        except KeyError:
            print ('Column name incomplete.')
            raise
        except Exception:
            print ('Unknown error.')
            raise
```

Consider having each of the helper methods `_read` et al. do their own logging, rather than catching and re-raising the exceptions in `__init__`.

`LanguagePack.__init__` may not know how to handle these errors, but whoever is creating the instance might. Let them decide whether to

- catch and ignore the exception that `__init__` itself (re)raises.
- try to instantiate the class again (in either the same or a different way)
- give up and exit the program
- do something else

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to keep the instance, although it could not be initialized correctly, you could just overload the `__getattr__` method and check for some flag you raise, when you catch an exception.

Answer (score -3):

You should use the `__new__` function:

```
class LanguagePack:
    def __new__ (cls):
        try:
            #do your checks here isntead of _read, _validator and _slice

        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            print ('File is not in UTF-8 (BOM) encoding.')
            return None
        except KeyError:
            print ('Column name incomplete.')
            return None
        except:
            print ('Unknown error.')
            return None

        else:
            #if you're class is of basic type object:
            return object.__new__(cls)
            #this will return the class object and call your init
    def __init__(self):
        #do some stuff if you need
        pass
```

Use `__new__` funcion only if you need to check something during the class creation or if you want to return something (`__init__` returns `None`)

Comment: There's no reason to use `__new__` over `__init__` here.